# What is the difference between spacy.lang.en and load('en')?

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter-notebook, spacy

In my studies on NLP, more specifically the spacy library, I was confused with that, 
what is the difference between `from spacy.lang.en import English()` and `spacy.load('en')` and how it works? Someone can help me explain this and if possible with some example of this difference? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The `English` language class in `spacy.lang.en` contains the language-specific code and rules included [in the library](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/spacy/lang/en) – for example, special case rules for tokenization, stop words or functions to decide whether a word like "twenty two" resembles a number.

`spacy.load("en")` loads the installed [statistical model](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#statistical-models) with the shortcut name `en` – in this case, the [`en_core_web_sm`](https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_sm) package. So you could also run `spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")`, which makes things a bit more explicit. Loading a model will initialize the respective language class (in this case, `English`), set up the processing pipeline and load in the binary weights of the trained model that allow spaCy to make predictions (e.g. whether a word is a noun or what named entities are in the text). So the `nlp` object you get back after loading a model is an *instance* of `English`, but it also has a processing pipeline set up and weights loaded in.

You can find a more detailed overview of how `spacy.load` works under the hood [here](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#pipelines). The [first chapter](https://course.spacy.io/chapter1) of the spaCy online course also explains the language classes and statistical models in more detail.

Comment: It should still work as described above if you have a shortcut for `en` created. For example, if you've downloaded the model via `spacy download en` or if you've created a shortcut `en` yourself using the `spacy link` command. If you just download the model via its full name `en_core_web_sm`, no shortcut will be created.